# Defining boundary conditions for spline interpolation via the Euler–Maclaurin formula

Tags: real-analysis, na.numerical-analysis, interpolation, splines

The [Euler–Maclaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) states an interdependency between

\begin{align}
I\quad:=&\quad\int_m^nf(x) \, dx,\ \ m,n\in\mathbb{Z},\\[6pt]
S\quad:=&\quad\sum_{k=m}^n f(k), \\[6pt]
D\quad:=&\quad\left\lbrace \frac{d^j}{dx^j} f(m) \right\rbrace \cup \left\lbrace \frac{d^j}{dx^j} f(n) \right\rbrace .
\end{align}

The Euler–Maclaurin formula is "traditionally" used to estimate the value of $S$ from $I$ and $D$ and also to estimate $I$ from $S$ and $D$.

> **Question:**
> are there examples where the Euler–Maclaurin formula has been beneficially used to fix the values of the derivatives of a function at the endpoints of its integration interval in order to fix the values of the elements of $D$ via $\lbrace I,\left(x_i,y_i\right)_{i=m}^n \rbrace$?

> *To be specific:* have there been attempts to determine the values of the elements of $D$ via the Euler–Maclaurin formula to find "ideal" derivatives for use in clamped spline-interpolation, i.e. where the disambiguation of the interpolation is done via fixing derivatives at the ends of the interpolation interval by plugging the (estimated) value of $I$ and/or the coordinate values of the $\left(x_i,f(x_i)\right)$ into the Euler–Maclaurin formula?

Comment: Why do you format this as $$\begin{align}
I\quad:=&&\int_m^nf(x) \, dx;\ m,n\in\mathbb{Z}\\ \\
S\quad:=&&\sum_{k=m}^n f(k) \\ \\
D\quad:=&&\left\lbrace \frac{d^j}{dx^j} f(m) \right\rbrace \cup \left\lbrace \frac{d^j}{dx^j} f(n) \right\rbrace 
\end{align}$$ rather than as seen below? $$\begin{align}
I\quad:=& \quad \int_m^nf(x) \, dx;\ m,n\in\mathbb{Z}\\ \\
S\quad:=& \quad \sum_{k=m}^n f(k) \\ \\
D\quad:=&\quad \left\lbrace \frac{d^j}{dx^j} f(m) \right\rbrace \cup \left\lbrace \frac{d^j}{dx^j} f(n) \right\rbrace 
\end{align}$$

Comment: @MichaelHardy unfortunately I don't have the chance to do frequent mathematical type setting and thus lack some expertise in that respect. I will adopt your suggested formatting, which looks much nicer.